# How to assign one-to-many relationship objects to variable?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Apologies for the confusing and probably inaccurate title.

At any rate, I have two CoreData entities. Listing and Comment. A listing can have multiple comments so the entity models reflect this.

```
extension Listing {

    @NSManaged var listingTitle: String?
    @NSManaged var comments: NSSet?
}

extension Comment {

    @NSManaged var comment: String?
    @NSManaged var commentId: String?
    @NSManaged var rating: Int32
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var listing: Listing?

}
```

At some point in the app I want to populate a UITableView with the comments but I'm having a bit of a hard time doing so.

```
var listing: Listing?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //I assumed I could do this
    var comments: [Comment] = [Comment]()
    comments = listings?.comments // This throws an error saying NSSET cant be assigned to type [Comment]
```

Could anyone guide me to the correct way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do here? I can see the issue being related to the fact that in the Listing entity the commments are defined as a NSSet of an udefined type, so I probably cant assign that NSSet directly to an array of Comment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can access your above listing->comments as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var listing = Listing()

        //Assign listing coredata object according to your values and save it.


        //Fetch above listing comments in array format and use it according to your requirement.

        var listingComments:Array = listing.comments!.allObjects
        let commentFirst:Comment = listingComments[0] as! Comment
        print(commentFirst.commentId)
        print(commentFirst.comment)
        print(commentFirst.rating)
        print(commentFirst.username)
    }
```

listingComments is similar to your declared variable 'var comments:[Comment]', You don't require to explicitly write [Comment], you can access of NSSet objects by it's allObjects property and assign it to Array object.

Answer (score 0):

```
comments = (listings?.comments.alObjects as! [Comment]) ?? []
```

This line should do it.

Comment: Hmm, I take it you mean as! [Comment] )  ?? [] 

In which case I get "Cast from NSSet? to unrelated type [Connection] always fails" warning.

EDIT: Ah, adding the "allObjects" in there removed the warning at least. I will accept the answer once Ive verified that it really does work :) Thank you!

Comment: if you add another line somewhere else like: `let test = listings!.comments.allObjects as! [Comment]` (for debugging purpose). Will that throw an error?